# can we create an object of class inside instance block?

Tags: java

```
class ObjectCreation {
    {
        ObjectCreation obj = new ObjectCreation();
        System.out.println("I am Instance Block Object " + obj.hashCode());
    }     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectCreation obj = new ObjectCreation();
        System.out.println("I am main method Object " + obj.hashCode());
    }
}
```

.java:5)
at ObjectCreation.(ObjectCreation.java:5)

I found this runtime exception on console. Why we are not able to create object of same class?
in instance block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it would lead to an infinite loop.

So in your main code you want to create a new instance of ObjectCreation, like so :

```
 ObjectCreation Obj = new ObjectCreation();
```

So the JVM has to initialise that new object, which means it will call the instance block for it - which does a

```
ObjectCreation Obj = new ObjectCreation();
```

So the JVM has to initialise that new object, which means it will call the instance block for it - which …

well, you get the idea !

Comment: If we made the initializer static (rather than instance), would that solve the problem?

Comment: It avoids the infinite loop (actually recursion) but it is unclear if it solves the "problem". We don't know what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Initializer blocks are used to initialize instance variables. Post compilation, Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Read more about initializer block [here](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/02/initializer-blocks.html).